# Mustache-like language with knockout-observables

Tags: knockout.js, handlebars.js, mustache, nunjucks

I am trying to use a Knockout-style view-model with a mustache-like language.

So the view model looks something like this:

```
var viewModel = {
  aValue: ko.observable("boot")
}
```

The rather common problem with mustache-like languages is that they do not unwrap the models.  So one gets e.g.

```
mustache_lib.render("{{ aValue }}", viewModel)
   => "function (initialvalue) { function observable() { ..."
```

That's what happens with Nunjucks, among others (with their respective `render` function).

One could use a filter with Nunjucks, so the following works as expected:

```
nunjucks.renderString("{{ aValue | unwrap }}", viewModel)
   => "boot"
```

Where `unwrap` is a filter, being `ko.unwrap`.  However I am not a fan of the syntax, and I was wondering if there were a better option.  I perused Nunjucks code and it did not seem possible to automatically unwrap every variable looked up in a context.

Handlebars.js has a preferable syntax (in my eyes), e.g.

```
Handlebars.compile("{{ unwrap aValue }}")(viewModel)
   => "boot"
```

Unfortunately if you forget the `unwrap`, then `aValue` will be treated as a helper and called with an undesirable value, something like `{ data: Object, hash: '', name: '...' }`.  Obviously one prefers not to have their templating language do this.  Similar to Nunjucks, Handlebars does not have a way to modify the context lookups to automatically call `ko.unwrap`.

Interestingly, Mustache.js will call any variable that is a `function` (including, of course, observables).  However it lacks a number of features in other libraries.

Has anyone had any experience with using Mustache-like libraries with Knockout and worked through the relationship (including which mustache libraries are most suitable)?

Comment: An interesting (but probably not feasible) approach could also be to define `getter` and `setter` methods in your viewmodel's observables. Like in this example by Ryan Niemeyer: https://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/mrCSH/ I can imagine you want to find a solution in the templating part though, instead of changing the way you define your viewmodels...

Comment: @user3297291 Yes, that's definitely an option, too, which I should've mentioned. One could use Steve Sanderson's [Knockout-es5](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5) for this.  That said, Knockout-ES5 is not always suitable.

Comment: Incidentally, I find LinkedIn's `dust.js` to be quite forgiving in many of the right ways. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I ended up using dust.js, and making ko.subscribable's `thenable` by adding a `then` function to `ko.subscribable.fn` (with `then` resolution being prioritized in the next release of dust.js).